# HEROKU Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect

Tags: node.js, heroku

I pushed a project on Heroku and check and then go to

> More > View logs

This is my code:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));    

console.log("HELLO WORLD");
```

and display

```
2017-05-18T13:31:12.548867+00:00 app[api]: Release v15 created by user mail@mail.com
2017-05-18T13:31:12.548867+00:00 app[api]: Deploy a13cfedb by user mail@mail.com
2017-05-18T13:30:56.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-05-18T13:35:10.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user mail@mail.com
2017-05-18T13:35:26.442732+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 2beqer61 by user mail@mail.com
2017-05-18T13:35:26.442732+00:00 app[api]: Release v16 created by user mail@mail.com
2017-05-18T13:35:10.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-05-18T13:57:04.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user mail@mail.com
2017-05-18T13:57:21.455262+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 31d134 by user mail@mail.com
2017-05-18T13:57:21.455262+00:00 app[api]: Release v17 created by user mail@mail.com
2017-05-18T13:57:04.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
```

I tried to google the error but it seem that anybody else got the same error as me.
Does anyone can explain me how to fix it ?

Answer (score 11):

It's nothing related to your code. It's only the Heroku log that stops updating. If you press F5, it's going to connect again, and you'll be able to see what's going in the logs.

If you want to see your logs in your own console, you can also use the command `heroku logs --app [YOURAPPNAMEHERE]`, as long as you have [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) installed on your system.

Comment: I can confirm that, I never had that error message but since some time I am seeing it in Heroku logs without any code change.

Answer (score 0):

I just refreshed my browser, that error disappears. I don't that error is caused by the application we are hosting. It is the error from heroku side.