# Why isn't my Heroku hosting discord bot going online?

Tags: heroku, discord.py

[Hello, i am a complete cookie to coding so need some help.

I made a discord ModMail Bot using this repository(https://github.com/kyb3r/modmail) and used heroku to deploy the worker. Everything worked out and bot was working smoothly, but today it went offline, and when i tried restarting the worker, this messages show up. PLease help.][Code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWtZ5.png)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44050536/heroku-disconnected-from-log-stream-there-may-be-events-happening-that-you-do-n/44052993) help?

Answer (score 1):

Your bot does not stay *permanently* online when using heroku.

You'll have to wait until the bot eventually comes online, or pay for more dyno hours, which at this point, you could just host your bot on a VPS

Comment: can you suggest me a good hosting site for my purpose? i think i will need it for my log viewer and the bot itself